# Separate onClick event for parent and child element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have JSX code like this:

```
<div id="parent" onClick={clickOnParent} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}>
  <div id="child" onClick={clickOnChild} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
</div>
```

When I click on `parent` (outside the `child`) it will run `clickOnParent`, and when I click the `child` it will run both `clickOnParent` and `clickOnChild` of course.
Now I want to trigger only `clickOnChild` and ignore `clickOnParent` when clicking exactly on the `child`. How can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation#:%7E:text=The%20stopPropagation()%20method%20of,on%20links%20are%20still%20processed.)

```
const clickOnChild = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please what if i want to pass a value to it, say the id of what was clicked?? like this clickedOnChild(event,id)